# TensorFlow: product equivalent of tf.add_n

Tags: python, tensorflow

Is there a product equivalent of tf.add_n, returning the elementwise product of a list of tensors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution 1:

You can use higher order functions tf.foldl and tf.foldr. Here is an example:

```
x = tf.constant([5, 2, 4, 3])
y = tf.constant([2, 2, 1, 6])
z = tf.constant([24, 2, 1, 6])

xyz=[x,y,z]
product = tf.foldl(tf.mul, xyz) 

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print product.eval()
```

Results:
[240   8   4 108]

Solution 2:
You can use tf.reduce_prod:

```
x = tf.constant([5, 2, 4, 3])
y = tf.constant([2, 2, 1, 6])
z = tf.constant([24, 2, 1, 6])

x=tf.reshape(x,[1,-1])
y=tf.reshape(y,[1,-1])
z=tf.reshape(z,[1,-1])
xyz=tf.concat(concat_dim=0, values=[x,y,z])

product = tf.reduce_prod(xyz, reduction_indices=0) 

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print xyz.eval()
    print product.eval()
```

Results:

xyz
[[ 5  2  4  3]

[ 2  2  1  6]

[24  2  1  6]]

product
[240   8   4 108]